# Unity AR Ground Plane Detector

Tags: unity, augmented-reality, vuforia

I need to check a "ground plane" to put objects over it without a marker, using Unity.

Right now I'm using Vuforia, but the Ground Plane on Vuforia only works on some devices, I tested on mine and my mother's Android phone, both modern and from different brands, didn't work. So it's not an option, because many many people couldn't use it.

Same with ARCore, asked me to install some sort of Google Services AR, which the download is locked for my phone.

Is there any way to use Unity with some kind of ground plane detector that many phones can "read" it? Any API, code, anything different that I didn't try yet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Being modern phone is not important.

first you need to check that your phone has **Gyro** asits most important feature that markerless AR use.

next you have to check android device supports ARCORE and for Iphone Device You need to check if it Supports ARKIT.
you can find list here: https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices

you need to enable XR and ARKIT support in unity.

if all of these are done, its your bug. you can edit you question with you code or project image for better answer

Comment: Yeah, I got it, and I'm using AR without ground plane, all good. The problem is this, check: https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/vuforia-fusion-supported-devices.html you will see lots of Galaxies, not so much on another models.

Comment: and the link you sent, same thing, few models supports ARCore. So I need a workaround, don't need to be perfect, just need it to work...